# Strange warning in a C function const multidimensional-array argument

Tags: c, function, multidimensional-array, constants, arguments

I'm getting some strange warnings about this code:

```
typedef double mat4[4][4];

void mprod4(mat4 r, const mat4 a, const mat4 b)
{
/* yes, function is empty */
}

int main()
{
    mat4 mr, ma, mb;
    mprod4(mr, ma, mb);
}
```

`gcc` output as follows:

```
$ gcc -o test test.c
test.c: In function 'main':
test.c:13: warning: passing argument 2 of 'mprod4' from incompatible pointer
type
test.c:4: note: expected 'const double (*)[4]' but argument is of type 'double
(*)[4]'
test.c:13: warning: passing argument 3 of 'mprod4' from incompatible pointer
type
test.c:4:
note: expected 'const double (*)[4]' but argument is of type 'double
(*)[4]'
```

If I define the function as:

```
void mprod4(mat4 r, mat4 a, mat4 b)
{
}
```

Or defining matrices in main as:

```
mat4 mr;
const mat4 ma;
const mat4 mb;
```

Or call the function in main as:

```
mprod4(mr, (const double(*)[4])ma, (const double(*)[4])mb);
```

Or even defining `mat4` as:

```
typedef double mat4[16];
```

Makes the warning go away. What is happening here? Am I doing something invalid?

The gcc version is 4.4.3, if relevant.

I also posted on gcc bugzilla: http://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=47143

My current workaround is making ugly macros that cast stuff for me:

```
#ifndef _NO_UGLY_MATRIX_MACROS

#define mprod4(r, a, b) mprod4(r, (const double(*)[4])a, (const double(*)[4])b)

#endif
```

---

Answer from Joseph S. Myers on gcc bugzilla:

> Not a bug.  The function parameters
>   are of type "pointer to array[4] of
>   const double" because const on an
>   array type applies to the element
>   type, recursively, and then the
>   outermost array type, only, of a
>   parameter of array type decays to a
>   pointer, and the arguments passed are
>   of type "pointer to array[4] of
>   double" after array-to-pointer decay,
>   and the only case where qualifiers are
>   permitted to be added in assignment,
>   argument passing etc. is qualifiers on
>   the immediate pointer target, not
>   those nested more deeply.

Sounds pretty confusing to me, like the function expects:

```
pointer to array[4] of const doubles
```

and we are passing

```
pointer to const array[4] of doubles
```

intead.

Or would it be the inverse? The warnings suggest that the function expects a:

```
const double (*)[4]
```

which seems to me more like a

```
pointer to const array[4] of doubles
```

I'm really confused with this answer. Could somebody who understands what he said clarify and exemplify?

Comment: Something is seriously wrong here. The code in the question is correct and gives no errors or warnings. The messages in the question would be produced by `void mprod4(mat4 r, const double a[4][4], const double b[4][4])` , which is quite different.  The "accepted" answer does not explain this at all : the accepted answer explains why `T**` cannot convert to `const T**` but that is irrelevant as that is not what's happening here (arrays and pointers are different).

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I believe the problem is the constraints specified in *C99* **6.5.16.1(1)**, which seem to prohibit mixing qualifications in assignments, except for pointers for which an inclusive-qualifier exception is defined. The problem is that with indirect pointers, you end up passing a pointer to one thing to a pointer to another. The assignment isn't valid because, if it was, you could fool it into modifying a const-qualified object with the following code:

```
const char **cpp;
char *p;
const char c = 'A';
cpp = &p;  // constraint violation
*cpp = &c; // valid
*p = 0;    // valid by itself, but would clobber c
```

It might seem reasonable that `cpp`, which promises not to modify any `char`s, might be assigned a pointer to an object pointing at non-qualified `char`s. After all, that's allowed for single-indirect pointers, which is why, e.g.,  you can pass a mutable object to the second parameter of `strcpy(3)`, the first parameter to `strchr(3)`, and many other parameters that are declared with `const`.

But with the indirect pointer, at the next level, assignment from a qualified pointer is allowed, and now a perfectly unqualified pointer assignment will clobber a qualified object.

I don't immediately see how a 2-D array could lead to this situation, but in any case it hits the same constraint in the standard.

Since in your case, you aren't actually tricking it into clobbering a const, the right thing for *your* code would seem to be inserting the cast.

---

**Update:** OK guys, as it happens this issue is **[in the C faq](http://c-faq.com/ansi/constmismatch.html)**, and this entire discussion has also taken place several times **[on the gcc bug list](http://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=20230)** and on the gcc mailing list.

- Gcc bug list: **http://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=20230**.
- C FAQ: it's question 11.10: **http://c-faq.com/ansi/constmismatch.html**

The lesson: you can pass a `T *x` when `const T *x` is expected, by explicit exception, but `T *x` and `const T *x` are still distinct types, so you can't pass a pointer to either one to a pointer to the other.

Comment: See my comment below. I don't see why you think that 6.5.16.1(1) is violated. You can add qualifiers (say, assign a non-const to a const), you just can't remove them.

Comment: Thanks, but I see no constraint violation in your example. const char **cpp means that we are not allowed to change the memory pointed by (**cpp) right? If so, only violation here would be (**cpp) = 0. Correct me if I am wrong please.

Comment: +1 My conclusion is different than yours, but we both agree that this is a valid problem.

Comment: There IS a violation of 6.5.16.1(1) in the line "cpp=&p;", because the type pointed to by cpp (which is 'a pointer to a const char') is incompatible with the type of p ('a pointer to a char'). But this whole exercise seems irrelevant to the original problem.

Comment: Oh, sorry, i see now why it would be bad to do this. Disregard my last comment.

Comment: Heh, rogi, that example is pasted directly from C99 6.5.16.1. (Ahem, under the *Fair Use* doctrine.) I'm glad you figured it out on your own. I had to read it three times, each time a bit slower.

Comment: Thank you very much, that situation is REALLY confusing lol. Issue solved.

Comment: Hope google find this easily. I googled alot and could not find any explanation on this.

Answer (score 6):

To explain what Joseph said: the function is expecting a `pointer to array[4] of const double` to be passed in, but you're passing in a `pointer to array[4] of double`.  These types are not compatible, so you get an error.  They look like they should be compatible, but they're not.

For the purposes of passing parameters to functions (or for variable assignments), you can always convert an `X` to a `const X`, or a `pointer to X` to a `pointer to const X` for any type `X`.  For example:

```
int x1 = 0;
const int x2 = x1;  // ok
int *x3 = &x1;
const int *x4 = x3;  // ok: convert "pointer to int" to "pointer to const int"
int **x5 = &x3;
const int **x6 = x5;  // ERROR: see DigitalRoss's answer
int *const *x7 = x5;  // ok: convert "pointer to (pointer to int)" to
                      //             "pointer to const (pointer to int)"
```

You're only allowed to add qualifiers (that is, the `const`, `volatile`, and `restrict` qualifiers) to the *first* level of pointers.  You can't add them to higher levels of pointers because, as [DigitalRoss mentioned](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4573349/c-function-const-multidimensional-array-argument-strange-warning/4573484#4573484), doing so would allow you to accidentally violate const-correctness.  This is what Joseph means by "the only case where
qualifiers are permitted to be added in assignment, argument passing etc. is
qualifiers on the immediate pointer target, not those nested more deeply."

So, bringing us back to Joseph's response, you can't convert a `pointer to array[4] of double` to a `pointer to array[4] of const double` because there is no type `X` such that you're converting from `pointer to X` to `pointer to const X`.

If you try using `array[4] of double` for `X`, you'd see that you *can* convert to `pointer to const array[4] of double`, which is a different type.  However, no such type exists in C: you can have an array of a `const` type, but there is no such thing as a `const array`.

Hence, there's no way to perfectly solve your problem.  You'll have to either add casts to all of your function calls (either manually or via a macro or helper function), rewrite your functions to not take `const` parameters (bad since it doesn't let you pass in `const` matrices), or change the `mat4` type to be either a 1-dimensional array or a structure, as [user502515 suggested](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4573349/c-function-const-multidimensional-array-argument-strange-warning/4573903#4573903).

Comment: this answer is well explained. Thanks! And now I can go to sleep ;)

Answer (score 2):

To practically solve this, one could use a struct, and the change of `double[4][4]` into the a-bit-awkward `double (*)[4]` is avoided, and constness also works intuitively — while the same amount of memory is used:

```
struct mat4 {
        double m[4][4];
};

void myfunc(struct mat4 *r, const struct mat4 *a, const struct mat4 *b)
{
}

int main(void)
{
        struct mat4 mr, ma, mb;
        myfunc(&mr, &ma, &mb);
}
```

Comment: Thanks for teh suggestion but sorry, its very annoing to write everywere a->m[i][j]. I'm trying to do stuff in a way so I need only to write a[i][j]. In fact I know how to work around this, what bothers me is WHY this happens.

Comment: @rogi: Because C is a very old language, designed to compile code that was written in it thirty years ago, not deal with this newfangled const stuff. That's pretty much why.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a problem (IMHO): `double[4][4]` in a function signature.

*You* know it's a `double[4][4]`, but the compiler sees `double(*)[4]` in the function paramter list, which notably has no array size constraint. It turns your 2D array of 4 by 4 objects into a pointer to a 1D array of 4 objects, and the pointer can be validly indexed as if it were an array of 4 objects.

I would pass all `mat4` objects by pointer:

```
void mprod4(mat4 *r, const mat4 *a, const mat4 *b);
// and, if you don't want to hairy your syntax
#define mprod4(r, a, b) (mprod4)(&r, (const mat4 *)&a, (const mat4 *)&b)
```

This will (I believe) ensure const correctness *and* array size correctness. It may make `mprod4` a bit harder to write, and still involves some hairy casts, but it'll (IMHO) be worth it (especially after the macro above):

```
void mprod4(mat4 *r, const mat4 *a, const mat4 *b)
{
    // all indexing of the matricies must be done after dereference
    for(int i = 0; i < 4; i++) for(int j = 0; j < 4; j++)
      {
        (*r)[i][j] = (*a)[i][j] * (*b)[i][j];
        // you could make it easier on yourself if you like:
        #define idx(a, i, j) ((*a)[i][j])
        idx(r, i, j) = idx(a, i, j) * idx(b, i, j)
      }
}
```

It may look a bit bad when you write it, but I think it'll be cleaner type-wise. (Maybe I've been thinking C++ too much...)

Comment: Const correctnes is achieved by making const mat4 a. Thanks anyway for your example, maybe its better to write stuff this way.

Comment: Sorry, In fact const correctness wasn't achieved in my case, even though teh compiler would behave teh way i wanted it to when assigning stuff. Disregard my last comment.

Answer (score 1):

I think in C99, you can do this, but I'm not sure it will help:

```
void mprod4(double mr[4][4], double ma[const 4][const 4], double mb[const 4][const 4])
{

}
```

I haven't got a C99 compiler handy but I remember reading something in the C99 specification regarding qualifiers within the `[]` for arrays as arguments. You can also put `static` in there (e.g. `ma[static 4]`) but of course that means something else.

#### Edit

Here it is, section 6.7.3.5 paragraph 7.

> A declaration of a parameter as “array of type” shall be adjusted to “qualified pointer to type”, where the type qualifiers (if any) are those specified within the `[` and `]` of the array type derivation. If the keyword `static` also appears within the `[` and `]` of the array type derivation, then for each call to the function, the value of the corresponding actual argument shall provide access to the first element of an array with at least as many elements as specified by the size expression.

Comment: Glad I revived this question. I did not know about this feature. Checking it out now...

Comment: I'm also not sure you can `typedef` this since qualifiers within `[]` is only valid for function arguments.

Comment: Haven't tested, I believe the relevant part of the standard is §6.7.5.3, part 7: "A declaration of a parameter as "array of type" shall be adjusted to "qualiﬁed pointer to type", where the type qualifiers (if any) are those speciﬁed within the `[` and `]` of the array type derivation. If the keyword `static` also appears within the `[` and `]` of the array type derivation, then for each call to the function, the value of the corresponding actual argument shall provide access to the ﬁrst element of an array with at least as many elements as speciﬁed by the size expression."

Comment: @Chris Lutz: LOL I was just adding it to my answer as you commented.

Comment: @dreamlax - Nice. GCC (4.0) is telling me that the second array's `const` isn't allowed, but it doesn't seem to be `const`ing anything. I had to write `const double ma[const 4][4]` and then pass it via `*(const double (*)[4][4])&a` to the function to get the `const`ing to work. :(

Comment: @Chris: Interesting results. I'm sad that it wasn't the solution :( though.

Comment: Sorry, this doesn't seem to explain anything.

Answer (score -1):

Compiler is just being anal.

You're passing an argument that is essentially a non-const pointer, and the function is declared to accept a const pointer as an argument. These two are, in fact, incompatible. It is not a real problem because the compiler is still supposed to work as long as you can assign the value of the first type to the variable of the second type. Hence a warning but not an error.

EDIT: looks like gcc does not complain about other con-const to const conversions, e.g. passing char* where a const char* is expected. In this case, I'm inclined to agree that Joseph Myers from Bugzilla is correct.

Comment: I believe this is incorrect. The standard prohibits zillions of things that the compilers merely warn about, because they need to compile legacy code. (And because you can always tell the compiler to treat warnings as errors.)  This particular case violates a constraint in the C99 standard. The reasons are complicated but I have given an example.

Comment: Which part is incorrect? Types are incompatible according to the section 6.7.3.9 of ANSI C standard. Assignment is allowed according to 6.5.16.1(1): "both operands are pointers to qualified or unqualified versions of compatible types, and the type pointed to by the left has all the qualifiers of the type pointed to by the right." The type on the right has no qualifiers, so we're fine.

Comment: Thanks. What you said make sense to me. I just dont see why my anal compiler warns about 2d arrays and not 1d ones.

Comment: Try to declare the function as "void mprod4(double* r, const double* a, const double* b)" and try to pass it a 'double*' as the second argument. Do you get the warning?

Comment: Now I get teh warning even for teh first argument LOL. And I need it to be mat4 so I can write a[i][j] to index stuff rather than a[i*4+j] which is kinda annoying.

Comment: I was trying to be polite, but I will make it clearer: *this is not the correct answer.* According to this answer, passing a mutable object to, say, **const char x[4]** or **const char \*x** would also be invalid, but in fact it is not. No warning is generated.  Look at **strcpy()**, **strchr()**, and many others.  I agree that the OP brings up a complex issue, but this answer is *obviously* wrong.

Comment: We can look at some of the C99 library: **char \*strchr(const char \*s, int c)** or how about **char \*strcpy(char \*restrict s1, const char \*restrict s2)** Also, the "Hence a warning but not an error." explanation is also incorrect. The compiler issues warnings for all type clashes that would have been accepted by K&R or earlier language revisions. The warning-not-error policy has to do with legacy code, not whether it is "a real problem". Nothing in C99 defines "a real problem".

Comment: "A real problem" means a violation of the standard. There's no violation of the standard here. Warnings are often emitted to inform the user when he tries to compile technically valid code which may have undesirable side effects (e.g. implicitly casting float to integer).

Comment: In fact, there WAS a violation. See teh elected answer. Very tricky in fact.