# Call a c function with a const matrix argument using a const cast

Tags: c, matrix, casting, constants

I am trying to call a c function with a const matrix argument using a const cast, but can't find the syntax that stops the gcc compiler complaining.  The code below compiles without complaining if all "const " casts are removed.  The quesion is similar to [C function const multidimensional-array argument strange warning](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4573349/c-function-const-multidimensional-array-argument-strange-warning) but no fully satisfactory solution was offered there.  In the following code, if the first call to g() works, then the second call to g() *should* also work, since it is syntactically identical.  But it does not.  The second version of g() is preferred, because it does not require knowing in advance the type of the matrix.

```
/* file t.c */
void f(const int a[2]) {/*empty*/}
void g(const int b[2][2]) {/*empty*/}

int main()
{
    int a[2];
    int b[2][2];

    f((const int (*)) a);                   /* ok */
    f((const typeof(&a[0])) a);             /* ok */
    g((const int (*)[2]) b);                /* ok */
    g((const typeof(&b[0])) b);             /* compiler complains */
}

$ gcc -o t t.c
t.c: In function ‘main’:
t.c:13:2: warning: passing argument 1 of ‘g’ from incompatible pointer type [enabled by default]
  g((const typeof(&b[0])) b);  /* compiler complains */
  ^
t.c:3:10: note: expected ‘const int (*)[2]’ but argument is of type ‘int (*)[2]’
     void g(const int b[2][2]) {/*empty*/}
```

Comment: `const typeof(&b[0])` is `int (* const)[2]`, not `const int (*)[2]`, i.e. the pointer itself is const, not the elements.

Comment: The cast doesn't do anything useful. You can just call the functions as `f(a)` and `g(b)`.

Comment: Yes, one can just call the functions as f(a) and g(b), and everything works. The problem is simply the compiler complaining. I have a large code that calls library functions with const arguments. gcc litters the compilation with complaints that should not be there.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, this lack of possibility to call a function with `const` 2D arrays with a non-`const` argument is really a defect in the C specification.

To move around it remember that

```
void g(const int b[2][2]) {/*empty*/}
```

is rewritten as

```
void g(const int (*b)[2]) {/*empty*/}
```

so this shows you how you'd have to convert, to a `const int (*)[2]`, that is a pointer to an array of 2 `double`.

```
g( (const int (*)[2])b );
```

Comment: The gcc error message is also helpful in remembering how to write the type: `expected 'const int (*)[2]' but argument is of type 'int (*)[2]'`

Comment: This is all correct.  The issue is that int (*)[2])b should be the same as typeof(&b[0]) (I think), but the compiler does not recognize them as the same.

Comment: @ajsh, no it should be the same as `typeof(&b)` without the `[0]`.

Answer (score -1):

The const in the declaration header means that the function cannot change the contents of the argument. It is an information to the caller(compiler) and programmer. So there is no reason to make a const typecast then calling the function. It is totally superfluous.

Comment: It would be superfluous if it were not for the compiler error. http://ideone.com/Oow2hn

Comment: I didn't know, the compiler did that. Very weird behavior.